# Let A be a square matrix such that $A^3 = 2I$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Let $A$ be a square matrix such that $A^3 = 2I$

i) Prove that $A - I$ is invertible and find its inverse

ii) Prove that $A + 2I$ is invertible and find its inverse

iii) Using (i) and (ii) or otherwise, prove that $A^2 - 2A + 2I$ is invertible and find its inverse as a polynomial in $A$

$I$ refers to identity matrix.

Am already stucked at part i). Was going along the line of showing that $(A-I)([...]) = I$ by manipulating the equation to $A^3 - I = I$ and I got stuck... :(

Comment: Is there any information about order of matrix $A$

Comment: Hello! Nope there isnt :(

Comment: $A^3-I=(A-I)(A^2+A+I)$. But $A^3-I=I$.  So $A^2+A+I$ is the inverse of $A-I$. Now it's your turn.

Comment: Have you tried a search on this website before asking your question? One can easily find: [this for the first question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1649076/a-is-a-square-matrix-and-given-that-a3-2-mathbbi-then-show-a-mathbbi/) and [this for the third question (looked at Dario's answer in particular!)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1378132/show-that-b-is-invertible-if-b-a2-2a2i-and-a3-2i)

Comment: If you know about minimal polynomials, it suffices to note that the minimal polynomial of $A$ divides $x^3 - 2$.  So, $A - \lambda I$ will necessarily be invertible if $\lambda^3 \neq 2$.

Answer (score 8):

If $A^3 = 2 I$, then you know that if $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then $A^3 v = A (A (A v) = \lambda^3 v$. But, since $A^3 = 2 I$, you have $\lambda^3 v = 2 v$ or $\lambda^3 = 2$.

There are 3 cube roots of $2$, none of which is $1$ or $-2$. Thus, $A-I$ and $A+2I$ are invertible (they have trivial nullspaces, since 1 and -2 are not eigenvalues).

Comment: This is gem of an answer assuming that the person who asked this knows what eigenvalues are..

Comment: How do we know that `v` exists?

Comment: Eigenvalues was not taught in class.. but really appreciate the help! :D

Comment: @SharmaineSwee : You can appreciate by upvoting this answer... There are two arrows to the left of this answer.. One which points above one which points below.. If you like this, you click the one which points above if you do not like this you click the one which points below..

Comment: @sav - fair point; if we're working over C, we're fine.

Answer (score 2):

We have $A^3-2I=0$ which is same as $A^3-I=I$

Recall the formula $a^3-b^3=(a-b)(***)$

Comment: Hello, please correct me if i'm wrong~ we can use $a^3 - B^3$ to factorize because identity matrix I can be treated as the value 1, which is the same as factorizing $A^3 - 1$ (can be done using the long division method) ?? Which derives the equation $(A-1)(A^2 + A + I)$

Comment: Yes Yes.. You are correct..

Answer (score 1):

For finding the inverse of $B_a=A-aI$ (provided it exists), write $A=B_a+aI$; then
$$
(B_a+aI)^3=B_a^3+3aB_a^2+3a^2B_a+a^3I
$$
so you have
$$
B_a^3+3aB_a^2+3a^2B_a=(2-a^3)I
$$
and multiplying by $B_a^{-1}$ gives
$$
B_a^{-1}=\frac{1}{2-a^3}(B_a^2+3aB_a+3a^2I)=
\frac{1}{2-a^3}(A^2+aA+a^2I)
$$
You see that the inverse exists provided $a^3\ne2$.

Can you do the last part?

Hint:
\begin{align}
A^2-2A+2I&=A^2-2A+A^3\\
&=A(A^2+A-2I)\\
&=A(A-I)(A+2I)
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

For parts (i) and (ii):
\begin{align}
             (A-I)^{-1} & = A^2+A+I \\
             (A+2 I)^{-1} & = \frac{1}{10}(A^2-2A+4).
\end{align}
For (iii):
$$
        A^2-2A+2I=A^2-2A+A^3=A(A+2I)(A-I)
$$
The inverse of $A$ is $\frac{1}{2}A^2$. So,
\begin{align}
     (A^2-2A+2I)^{-1}&=(A-I)^{-1}(A+2I)^{-1}A^{-1}\\
       &=\frac{1}{20}(A^2+A+I)(A^2-2A+4)A^2
\end{align}